# AMP is not displayed in Gmail

Tags: email, amp-html, mime, amp-email

I am experimenting with amp4email and have problems getting it to work.

This is how it looks in my Gmail:

[image: empty body in gmail]

I followed this Article: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/interaction_dynamic/amp-email-format

If I view "Original message" in Gmail this is how it looks:

```
Return-Path: <myemail@gmail.com>
Received: from localhost.localdomain ([80.234.101.191])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id z15sm3123981ljz.55.2019.03.28.01.27.34
        for <myemail@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 bits=256/256);
        Thu, 28 Mar 2019 01:27:34 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Thu, 28 Mar 2019 12:27:41 +0400
From: myemail@gmail.com
To: myemail@gmail.com
Message-ID: <5c9c857d5cfb0_a8083fccaec32e6c860ab@Dmitrys-MacBook-Pro-2.local.mail>
Subject: Test email from Dmitry
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/x-amp-html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!doctype html>
<html amp4email>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
  <style amp-custom>
    .red { background-color: red; }
    .blue { background-color: blue; }
    .yellow { background-color: yellow; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p [class]="state.color" class="yellow" [text]="'The current color is ' + state.color + '.'">
  The current color is yellow
</p>
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({state: {color: 'red'}})">
  Set color to red
</button>
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({state: {color: 'blue'}})">
  Set color to blue
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

p.s. I edited out my real email.

Answer (score 2):

I am testing the same and having trouble as well - I am not seeing the setting for enabling dynamic emails. Have you set it or is it missing for you too?
As per [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/testing-dynamic-email), you need to:

> Navigate to Gmail Settings > General > Dynamic email and click Dynamic
> email development. This opens a dialog where you can whitelist email
> addresses that can send you dynamic emails for testing purposes.

Comment: I don't see this section neither :-/

Comment: No updates yet, going to try Gmail community/help. Please let me know if this worked for someone.

Comment: Hard refresh of gmail made that setting show up for me. This is for a regular gmail address, a GSuite managed one has a GSuite managed setting.

Comment: Excellent! It showed up for me as well now and now the AMP email works after whitelisting the sender. I was accessing Gmail in private/incognito mode when checking before as well so this is something being rolled out gradually perhaps.

Comment: I have whitelisted the email in my Gmail settings, however AMP is still not displaying. Could there be another reason. I did send it through SparkPost. They have a neat AMP for email tab.

Comment: I used an SPF, DKIM, DMARC validated mail but it does not work. I whitelisted it on my Gmail but it is not shown as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Oddly enough, section did not show up in Edge and it did when in gmail via Chrome...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29852760)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Delivery Requirements section of the article "Test your AMP emails in Gmail" ([src](https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/testing-dynamic-email#delivery_requirements))

> The `From` and `To` header fields of the email must contain different email addresses.